# runtime error '1004' using Worksheets in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

Excel is throwing the error 1004. What am i doing wrong?

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim x As Variant
    x = Worksheets("Details").Range("A1").End(xlDown)
    If OptionButton65 = True Then Worksheets("Details").Cells(x, 6) = "5"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a very bad question but I guess the problem is that you don't assign a number x but a cell's value which is not an integer. If you change it as below, it might work.

```
x = Worksheets("Details").Range("A1").End(xlDown).row
```

Comment: Your assertion is incorrect. `x = Worksheets("Details").Range("A1").End(xlDown)` implicitly calls the default member for the `Range` object, which is `_Default`, which *will* return the *value* of the cell.

Answer (score 1):

First, since you are trying to get the row number, was a `Long` type variable for `x` , and not `Variant`.

Second, it depends what type of last row in column A you are trying to find:

**Option 1**: find last row without skipping blank cells in the middle.

**Option 2**: find last row with skipping blank cells in the middle.

Both options are implemented in my code below, use the option you want.

**Code**

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim x As Long

    With Worksheets("Details")
        ' option 1 : will get you the last row with data in Column A (without skipping blank cells in the middle)
        x = .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

        ' option 2 : will get you the last row with data in Column A (with skipping blank cells in the middle)
        x = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        If OptionButton65 = True Then .Cells(x, 6) = "5"
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to include another way of achieving this - you could have also used the `Range`, rather than it's `Row` property

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim x As Range
    Set x = Worksheets("Details").Range("F1").End(xlDown)
    If OptionButton65 = True Then x.Value = "5"
End Sub
```

or simply:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()     
    If OptionButton65 = True Then Worksheets("Details").Range("F1").End(xlDown).Value = "5"
End Sub
```